# sdb file: Database disk image is malformed

Tags: database, sqlite

I have an .sdb database with meteorological data created by the weewx software.
If I open it with sqlite3 and give integrity check command, I get the following

```
sqlite> PRAGMA integrity_check;
*** in database main ***
On tree page 27353 cell 0: invalid page number 27639
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_wind_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_wind_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_windBatteryStatus_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_windBatteryStatus_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_referenceVoltage_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_referenceVoltage_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_heatingVoltage_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_heatingVoltage_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_heatingTemp_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_heatingTemp_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_hail_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_hail_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_consBatteryVoltage_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_consBatteryVoltage_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_windGust_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_windGust_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_outTemp_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_outTemp_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_windchill_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_windchill_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_leafWet2_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_leafWet2_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_outTempBatteryStatus_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_outTempBatteryStatus_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_inTemp_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_inTemp_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_rainBatteryStatus_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_rainBatteryStatus_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_pressure_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_pressure_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_windSpeed_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_windSpeed_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_radiation_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_radiation_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_barometer_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_barometer_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_soilMoist2_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_soilMoist2_1
row 1820 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_leafWet1_1
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_archive_day_leafWet1_1
Runtime error: database disk image is malformed (11)
```

I have tried to give also the VACUUM command but it does not solve. It seems that the error is regarding only row 1820, and there is a wrong page number. Is there any way to try to fix this? Opening the sdb file with db browser for sqlite I can easily navigate into data.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/cli.html#recover_data_from_a_corrupted_database maybe